# How to implement last active time in web application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a webapp with creation of standart user sessions when a user logs in. I want to ask for an abstract flow of How to implement last active time of each user? I need that because I want to remove those user sessions which are expired by N time (configurable). I was thinking to create a Date field for User object and for each interaction of user with the server to update this Date, so that the object will always keep last interaction date. Is this a good approach or something better could be done? :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Which container do you use?? Usually it is implemented out of the box. For example you can configure it like this in tomcat (conf/web.xml):

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Sessions older than 30 minutes will be discarded.